# TYPO3 solr extension doesn't index

Tags: solr, typo3

I'm using solr 7.6 TYPO3 9.5 and the solr extension 9.0.2 for TYPO3. The solr server is contacted and it seems that everything is working well. I don't want to index pages of my TYPO3 installation, but a core that is listed as contacted but index Documents is emty and when I type a search word in the frontend I am getting an exception message from debugger:

ApacheSolrForTypo3\Solr\System\Solr\SolrUnavailableException: Solr Server not available: HTTP request failed, Server error: GET http://.........net:8983/solr/core_tr/select?omitHeader=false

How can I fix this or want went wrong here?[image]

Comment: What is the status code of the Server error - can you put in more of the output for that GET request to SOLR. What happens if you call that GET URL directly in your browser?

Comment: 500 Server Error` response: { "responseHeader":{ "status":500, "QTime":15, "params":{ "q":"hase", "defType":"edismax"

Comment: What does the solr error log say about this internal server error? 500 is quite fatal, obviously solr is not setup correctly (or has not enough resources).